# A subset of $\mathbb C\times\mathbb C$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-geometry

I'm trying to think if the space $\{(z,\,i\overline{z})\,:\,z\in\mathbb{C}\}$, where $\overline{z}$ is the complex  conjugate of $z$ and $i$ is the imaginary number, is topologically equivalent to another space.

I hope you can help me.

Comment: You surely mean $\{(z,i\bar z)\mid z\in\Bbb C\}$ ...

Comment: Any other space? Or a specific space?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Your space, call it $X$, is topologically equivalent to $\mathbb{C}$ with the homeomorphism given by the projection

$$\pi:X\rightarrow\mathbb{C},\, (z,i\overline{z})\mapsto z$$

Answer (score 0):

You need to show that
$$
f(z)=(z,i\bar z),
$$
is a homeomorphism between $\mathbb C$ and $X=f[\mathbb C]\subset \mathbb C\times\mathbb C$.

Is it clearly continuous and one-toone and onto, and its inverse is simply the projection $\pi_1$ of $\mathbb C\times\mathbb C$ onto $\mathbb C$.